# VerifyCsrfToken error with no status or message on line 82 Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, exception, csrf-token

In Exceptions/Handler.php i added some logic to send an email with every exception from my flow ( i added this to report method ).

In my flow i have severals forms and from time to time i get an email with an error on line 82 in file: `Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` . At this line is this "`throw new TokenMismatchException` ".

After reading some questions & answers i added `csrf token` to my forms.

The thing is i can't reproduce this error and the exception doesn't have any error code or message.

Beside that, in `laravel.log` there's no error about `csrf`.

My questions are:

1. Is this error flow breaking? I've made the flow several times and i didn't get any error, but if this exception will be throwed when a customer is in the flow, it will break the flow ( i mean it will be redirected to an error page ) or the client will know nothing?
2. Why this error is not in laravel.log?
3. Do you have any idea what can i do to fix this error?

Comment: *flow breaking* what flow? `TokenMismatchException` will be thrown if the csrf cant be validated due to the following invalid for whatever reason: 1) hidden field that store csrf value, 2) the cookies (both cookie for csrf itself and session). afaik

Comment: It is very easy to create the csrf token error. You just have to post a form without a csrf token...

Comment: Or change the token in the form before posting ofcource if your goal is TokenMismatchException